# QuickSort elementary Cases for an array of N numbers

Tags: algorithm, sorting

For an array of N numbers,what are the QuickSort elementary cases?
I thought that it's a sorting sequence of length N/2 as we use Divide and Conquer but i'm not so sure now

Comment: Elementary cases are those not divisible, N/2 is a sub-case, not an elementary case. If you google it, you will find tons of nice explanations on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that with "elementary case" you mean the recursion "base case". The base case occurs when quickSort is called with an array of size 0 or 1. As quick sort modifies the array in place, I should clarify that this *size* refers to the *range* within the array that represents the current partition.

When that range has 0 or 1 elements, it is (obviously) already sorted and so no further recursion should happen.

Typically `quickSort` looks like this:

```py
function quicksort(arr, low, high):
    if low >= high:  # base case
        return  # nothing to do
    pivot := partition(arr, low, high)
    # Recursion
    quicksort(arr, low, pivot - 1)
    quicksort(arr, pivot + 1, high)
```